# VarBinary field mapping to tinyint in DB when using MS Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a model

```
    public FileUpload(FileName, byte[] fileData,)
    {
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.FileData = fileData;
    }

    public FileName FileName { get; private set; }
    public byte[] FileData { get; private set; }
```

When creating the model

```
        modelBuilder.Entity("Model.FileUpload", b =>
            {
                b.Property<byte>("FileData")
                    .HasColumnType("varbinary(max)");
            }

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "FileUploads",
            columns: table => new
            {
                FileData = table.Column<byte>(nullable: true),
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                
            });
     }
```

When the database is created, the data type comes out as `TinyInt`, not `varbinary(max)` as expected, anyone know why this might be?

Comment: `b.Property<byte[]>`?

Comment: Ooh, it works, thanks @AlexB. it really was that simple ! Changing the 2 entries fixed it ! Need Coffee

Answer (score 0):

You have a small bug in your generic type defintion.

Change `byte` to `byte[]` array:

```
      modelBuilder.Entity("Model.FileUpload", b =>
        {
            b.Property<byte[]>("FileData")
                .HasColumnType("varbinary(max)");
        }

      migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "FileUploads",
        columns: table => new
        {
            FileData = table.Column<byte[]>(nullable: true),
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            
        });
 }
```